# Add additional namespace/schemalocations to XML file using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I want to convert:

```
<ppx xmlns="http://www.p.com/ppx/1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.p.com/ppx/1 http://www.p.com/ppx/1/ppx.xsd">
<p></p></ppx>
```

into:

```
<ppx xmlns="http://www.p.com/ppx/1" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:ppxx="http://www.m.com/mExt/v1" 
xmlns:ppxtpx="http://www.m.com/mExt/v3" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.p.com/ppx/1 http://www.p.com/ppx/1/ppx.xsd 
http://www.m.com/mExt/v1 http://www.m.com/mExt/v1/ppxv1.xsd 
http://www.m.com/mExt/v3 http://www.m.com/mExt/v3/ppxv3.xsd">
<p></p></ppx>
```

I need to add a few namespace declarations and their associated schemaLocations to an existing XML file without changing anything else in that XML.

Answer (score 1):

In principle it's easy: it just needs a standard "modified identity template" pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ppx">
<ppx xmlns="http://www.p.com/ppx/1" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:ppxx="http://www.m.com/mExt/v1" 
  xmlns:ppxtpx="http://www.m.com/mExt/v3" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.p.com/ppx/1 http://www.p.com/ppx/1/ppx.xsd 
    http://www.m.com/mExt/v1 http://www.m.com/mExt/v1/ppxv1.xsd 
    http://www.m.com/mExt/v3 http://www.m.com/mExt/v3/ppxv3.xsd">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </ppx>
</xsl:template>
```

However, it could get a bit more complicated depending on how much the input can vary from the example you have shown us. For example if the root element will not always be named `ppx`, or if the namespaces to be added are not known in advance. So you may need to explain more details of the problem

Comment: That worked :-) I made a minor change- the second template needs to be  <xsl:template match="/*"> for the case.